# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi-driver

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and when I click on settings and click on WiFi, it says `No Wi-Fi Adapter Found`.

I have a Windows 10 computer that is connected to the Internet.  Is there a way to download WiFi drivers for Ubuntu on the Windows 10 computer, if missing drivers is the problem, and put them on a USB drive and install them that way?

If so can you give instructions?

Comment: IIRC, when you install Ubuntu, it asks whether you want to include proprietary packages as part of the installation.  WiFi drivers are often proprietary.  If you just installed Ubuntu and didn't include that, and haven't yet invested a lot of time customizing it, the fastest solution may be to reinstall and select that option.  That will save you going through this again with drivers for the next piece of hardware.  Otherwise, you can identify the WiFi chipset, identify the driver package and install it.  Instructions can be found with a Google search, including previous questions here.

Comment: Alright. I couldnt find the support I needed for this. I had ubuntu on a usb drive from a while back and I didn't realize that there is a newer version out 19.04. I am going to install 19.04 and I will see if it gives me those options while installing, hopefully it will just install everything and I don't have to go through all of that. I will post what happens after I install. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to use 19.04, you're better off with 18.04.  18.04 is a long term support release, which has gone through a lot of testing to ensure it's stable.  19.04 is an interim release, which isn't much better than a beta test.  It's supported for just a few months while Canonical collects bug reports on it.

Comment: 19.04 for me is not showing a wifi option in settings and I have done a internet search for this information and I can't find what I am looking for. I need this to work soon. It's a hp laptop with a realtek wireless card in it. Can someone please help!? Links, videos, pictures?

Comment: I would like to download the driver the realtek wifi card and put it on a usb from my windows 10 computer and install it that way if possible. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not really up on this, but I did a Google search on "realtek wifi driver ubuntu" and got 5 pages of results.  A few of the first were https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/how-to-install-realtek-wifi-driver.html and http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nstall-rtl8723de-wifi-driver-ubuntu-19-04/.  A similar search should at least get you started.  BTW, a Windows driver won't work in Linux.

Comment: I connected to the internet by tethering my iphone with lubuntu, and now I am trying to find out how to get the realtek drivers installed with terminal on lubuntu.

Comment: Instructions on how to tether iphone: Go to settings on iphone and click on mobile hotspot and you have to turn on the wireless hotspot and it then uses your data cell phones data, charges might apply, you can decide if thats alright with you or not. Then you can plug your phone into the computer with a wifi cable if you have one for the iphone and you should be connected to the internet now. There might be a way to tether with andriod phone but I don't have one that I can use so I can't do that as of now.

Comment: You can also connect to the internet with a ethernet cable.

Comment: I will post if I can find a way to install the wifi drivers.

Comment: Here are the instructions on how to install the realtek wireless drivers (my wireless card is realtek rtl8723de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the instructions on how to install the Realtek wireless drivers (my wireless card is Realtek rtl8723de). It should work the same if you have to git link for other wireless card drivers for Ubuntu or the instructions should be very similar.

**How to get rtl8723de drivers and install**

Note before you start: You need to find your wireless card or external wireless card (usb dongles model).  Then you need to go to this website https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupportedand to find out if your wireless card or wireless usb dongle is supported.  If it is not listed, then you need to type it into google.com and search for the type of card or dongle that you have to try to find the git link.  Find the git link and click on it to find out how to install it with the terminal by typing commands similar to below.

For this card you can follow these instructions below.

Somewhere within the instructions below, it is going to ask you to enter a secure boot password and you need to type one in there. When you type reboot and the computer reboots, you will see a menu that asks you if you want to type the `mok` password.  Select the option that says `mok` at the end (I don't remember what it says exactly, but you need to choose that option).  It will then say to enter the password; enter the password you chose, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then choose reboot from the options menu.

Once you login, at the top right of the Ubuntu screen, click the down arrow and select WiFi.  Choose the network you want to connect to, enter your WiFi password, and it should allow you to connect to your network.

To install, you have to type these instructions in a terminal window.  Open a terminal by clicking the small square boxes at the left bottom of your screen, and in search, type `terminal`.  Then enter these command:

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo depmod -a
```

Then reboot.

I will post a link to my website and a youtube video when I am finished completing a blog on this and a video.

These instructions should also work for No `Wi-Fi Adapter Found` In 19.04 (please correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: I corrected it. Thanks for letting me know about the type error.

Comment: This didnt work for Ubuntu 18.04 Wi-Fi Adapter Found!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've completely logged out from Windows 10 by restarting it. Simply shutting it down won't help. Restart Windows and then login to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If the solution listed above are not working, you can look for a colleague that has the same computer as yours with the same version of Ubuntu installed, and simply copy the folder `/lib/modules` of his computer and replace  the `/lib/modules` of your computer.

This work for me after 2 days of tried.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

yes, i also had this problem but it is definitely you missed something when you install Ubuntu.  so go back to Ubuntu bootable  DVD or USB and check each folder if there is some thing missed you will get an installation option then connect with wired network and install (it was broadcom in my case and i found it in a name called 'tool' folder) 
then check your wifi it works in my case.

Comment: That seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

I've looked at hundreds of links for fixing this issue, but this code finally fixed my issue.

It's really helpful and simple.

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git -b 5.0-up
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
sudo depmod -a
```

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. What you propose is exactly the same commands as in the accepted answer, except that all formatting is missing here. You could make your answer usable with some newlines improved formatting, but it would still add nothing new. Please consider deleting your answer. Ideally also upvoting the existing answer woudl be the right thing to do, but you need some more reputation to do this.